# Behaviour of a capacitor in a load powered by a constant current source

Tags: capacitor, current, source

It's said that capacitors are open circuits when there's a constant current, but it's also said that capacitors resist a voltage change. So which of these two holds true in the scenario I described in the title?

Comment: Capacitors do not behave like open-circuits when charged by a constant current. Where would the current go? Maybe I am missing something. Please draw a diagram to more clearly describe your problem.

Comment: well, that is sufficient to answer my question, thanks.

Comment: The voltage of a capacitor powered with a constant current will increase linearly with time.

Comment: Gorge the explanations here are for cases where the capacitor is the load, I read your title more like "I have a load and it also includes a capacitor" so it would be something like a parallel connection of a resistor and a capacitor. Then the analysis is quite different. That's why @polwel asked for a schematic. Also note that your statement in the question body concern two different analysis types: constant operation point and time domain analysis, which differ as well.

Answer (score 1):

For a DC voltage applied to a capacitor, once the capacitor is charged it does look like an open circuit. It is charged up, it takes no more current, so as far as the source is concerned it does look like an open circuit.

But let's say you have a voltage source feeding a resistor. The voltage is at a some level V1. Now increase the voltage to V2. The only change in current is the change in resistor current.

Now hang a capacitor across the resistor, and let it charge up to V1. When you change the voltage source, it will require even more current to bring up the capacitor voltage, but when the voltage finally reaches V2 the cap will no longer be drawing current and will once more look like an open circuit. The larger the cap, the more current the source will have to provide to get a given change in voltage. For any source which is not an ideal source (that is, it has an impedance greater than zero) it will take time to charge up the capacitor. So a step change in voltage will be "resisted" by the cap - for a while.

If you use a current source, the voltage on the cap will rise (or fall) at a constant rate, equal to the current divided by the capacitance. It is the fact that the voltage level is changing which means that you cannot (in this case) say that the cap acts as an open circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you (could) connect ideal constant current source (with infinite compliance, that is, can supply an infinite voltage) to a perfect capacitor (which never breaks down under voltage), the voltage across the capacitor would increase linearly(*) forever.

The "resistance" of the capacitor, given by the instantaneous value if V/I, would also increase linearly (as I is constant and V increasing).

In the real world of course, infinite voltage power supplies and infinite voltage caps don't exist. So things will hit a limit at some point - either when the source runs out of compliance (so the voltage cannot rise any more) or the cap breaks down.

So the "resistance" of the cap is NOT constant - at least not until it is fully charged, at which point current falls to zero and the source is no longer constant current.

(*) the rate of change of voltage is easily found from basics:

I = dQ/dt

and

Q = C.V

therefore

I = dQ/dt = C.dV/dt

Answer (score -1):

Capacitor becomes an open circuit when charged by a constant current source. But if load voltage changes then capacitor voltage becomes twice the voltage.Also, in the scenario which was posted before, Voltage fluctuates means, “if voltage reverses, then load voltage aids by the capacitor voltage”.

Comment: "*Capacitor becomes an open circuit when charged by a constant current source.*" No, the fact that it is being charged means that current is flowing into it. (2) "*But if load voltage changes then capacitor voltage becomes twice the voltage.*" What load? Where does twice the voltage come from? (3) "*... in the scenario which was posted before ...*" Before what? It's not clear what this sentence is referring to. Welcome to EE.SE.